# How to pass List<Tuple> to another class?

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I'm trying to pass List pass to Windows form and there is error with adding records to this list(see code). In list are 3 params: MacAddress(string), Port(int), Time when packet arrived(DateTime). I want to refresh that list in listbox every 1 seconds.

```
    class Listen
        {
            Form1 mainForm;
            List<Tuple<string, int, DateTime>> list = new List<Tuple<string, int, DateTime>>();

            public Listen(Form1 mainForm)
            {
                this.mainForm = mainForm;
            }

            public List<Tuple<string, int, DateTime>> GetList()
            {
                return list;
            }

            public void AddtoList(string MacAddr, int deviceNumber, DateTime dt)
            {
                //ERROR:No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments
                list.Add(MacAddr, deviceNumber, dt);
            }

            public void StartListen(string deviceNum)
            {
             ...
                AddtoList(MacAddr.ToString(), deviceNumber, DateTime.Now);
             ...
            }
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Listen lis;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lis = new Listen(this);
            var devices = lis.GetDevices();
            comboBox2.DataSource = devices;
        }
public void PrintList()
        {
            lis = new Listen(this);
            var list = lis.GetList();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - list[i].Item3;
                listBox1.Items.Add(list[i].Item1 + "Port: " + list[i].Item2 + "Timer: " + ts);
            }

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintList();
        }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `Add` expects a `Tuple<string, int, DateTime>`, but you pass three single values. Try `list.Add(new Tuple<string, int, DateTime>(MacAddr, deviceNumber, dt);`.

Comment: okey, so every received packet will create new Tuple? How to pass it to listbox in class Form?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a list of a type you surely have to provide an instance of that specific type. There´s obviously not a method that supports all possible properties for every type. However create a new `Tuple`:

```
list.Add(new Tuple<string, int, DateTime>(MacAddr, deviceNumber, dt));
```

Comment: okey, so every received packet will create new Tuple? How to pass it to listbox in class Form?